# Como puedo hacer una funcion recursiva doble?

Tags: c++, dev-c++

Llegué a un punto en el programa que funciona, pero no como debería de funcionar: queda en un bucle infinito. Si alguien pudiese ayudarme y explicarme el porqué, se lo agradecería mucho:

```
int recursiva_doble(double entero){
    int cont=0;
    double copia = entero;
    system("color 0f");
    if(entero>=15){
        graficar_stack(copia);
    }
    if(cont==entero){
        return entero;
    }
    else{
        cont++;
        recursiva_doble(entero);
    }

}

int graficar_stack(double copia){
    system("color 05");
    int cont=0;
    cout<<"\n$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$ "<< sizeof(copia) <<" $$$$$$$$$$$$$$$"; 

    if(cont==copia){
        return copia;
    }
    else{
        cont++;
        return graficar_stack(copia);
    }
}
```

Comment: ¿Cómo se supone que debería funcionar? (y por cierto, a quedarse en un bucle infinito yo no lo llamaría "funcionar, pero no como debería" ;-))

Comment: @abulafia se supone debo de hacer que la recursiva de llame x cantidad definida por usuario y dsp, "graficar un stack" con el tamaño de bits del elemento que se denominó, eso en teoría.

Answer (score 1):

Para que la recursividad funcione necesitas dos cosas (principalmente) 1. el caso base (ese lo tienes). 2. que el problema se haga progresivamente más pequeño hasta llegar al caso base. Esto es lo que no tienes.

Cuando haces la llamada recursiva, la haces con el mismo argumento que en la llamada inicial, debes hacerlo más pequeño en cada llamada:

```
int recursiva_doble(double entero){
    int cont=0;
    double copia = entero;
    system("color 0f");
    if(entero>=15){
        graficar_stack(copia);
    }
    if(cont==entero){
        return entero;
    }
    else{
        cont++;
        recursiva_doble(--entero); // Este entero deberia ser mas pequeno para cada vez acercarse al caso base, por ej. `--entero`
    }

}
```

En tu otra función recursiva pasa exactamente lo mismo:

```
int graficar_stack(double copia){
    system("color 05");
    int cont=0;
    cout<<"\n$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$ "<< sizeof(copia) <<" $$$$$$$$$$$$$$$"; 

    if(cont==copia){
        return copia;
    }
    else{
        cont++;
        return graficar_stack(--copia); // Igual que arriba, el problema debe ser mas pequeño en cada llamada recursiva
    }
}
```

Si la llamada recursiva se hace con el mismo argumento (a menos que sea el caso base desde el inicio), nunca llegas al caso base y por eso te quedas en un bucle infinito.

PD: Esto no necesariamente soluciona el problema que necesitas solucionar, solo te explica el por qué del bucle infinito.

Comment: Funciona a medias, muchas gracias!!, ya veré como solucionar el problema que quedó :)